# Не запускается приложение в visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

В окне вывода ошибка, что "Файл перемещен, переименован или отсутствует на компьютере" подскажите, что в это случае можно сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас указан путь к временному файлу после извлечения из архива. Логично предположить, что этот файл был удалён после закрытия утилиты архиватора.

Извлеките файл по какому-то стабильному пути и открывайте его там.